# yahoo pipes trimming all item titles

Tags: regex, truncate, yahoo-pipes

After a lot of hard work, I have created two yahoo Pipes I will be using.

One of them has a minor problem however... I am trimming the title length down to leave enough room for a ... and a link to fit within a tweet.

It trims the first post correctly... however it trims all of the posts after that to 0 length (before adding a bit of extra text to the end).

The problem is I'm not using a loop for all items after a certain point, but the reason for that is the output is always items from a loop, and I need the output to be number at a certain point so that I can feed in that number asa  variable to trim the length by. The pipe can be found here: http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=3e6c3c6b2d23d8ce0cf66cb3efc5fb56

Typically, I am inserting any RSS feed in the top box, something like "new blog post:" in the middle and "#bussiness #hashtags" in the last box.

If you can see any way I can have this yahoo pipe work for all posts rather than just the top one, please let me know. its not a big deal as im only ever posting for the moment, the top post to twitter... however there may come a point where I need all of them looking the same.